# Android compileSdk 27 start service automatically show notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.1-oreo

I have an app that start a service. I know that Android Oreo has some limitations, so I started my service with this code:

```
context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), BeaconService.class));
```

In the BeaconService class in the onCreate() method I called startForeground() method.
I did it like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "MyApp",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        try {
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).build();
        startForeground(1, notification);

    }
```

My problem is that when this service is starting I got an empty notification that my app is running. Why? I don't want this notification when my app is running in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startForegroundService` implicitly calls `startForeground (int id, Notification notification)` as soon as the service starts. The notification you are seeing is because of this implicit call.

Comment: I know that, but from android 8.1 my users will got this notification?

Comment: Oh my god... Why? The app is running in foreground, so the user is seeing that my app is running... I think this is a very annoying "feature"

Comment: if i remember correctly this was introduced because of the limitation for background services they had added in the Android 8.0. They want that the user should know if there is a foreground service running.

Comment: On API 26 I didn't got this silly notification... But ok I will trying to accept this.. Thanks.

Comment: @just Foreground Services stay longer than Background Services, as Background ones can be stopped by System when needed

Comment: That's ok, but when the user starts the app can see "nearby users". If the user exit from my app or goes to the background I stop this service. So this is an unnecessary notification.